# Some standard Emacs keybindings don't work on my Linux box

Tags: emacs

On my macbook everything worked nicely, but on my Archlinux box, with dwm as a window manager, the following keybindings don't work:

- M-m
- M-<
- M->

It is kind of a pain to work without these bindings.  I should note that many other Meta key bindings work fine.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're probably being intercepted by your window manager.  I don't know dwm, but I'd try googling "dwm resetting keyboard shortcuts".

(A quick read of the results suggests dwm may need to be recompiled to do this, see http://dwm.suckless.org/)

Comment: right you are. In the dwm/config.h file the keybindings that are causing the problems exist.